# How load an emscripten generated module with es6 import?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying to import a module generated with emscripten as a es6 module.
I am trying with the [basic example](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code) from emscripten doc.

This is the command I am using to generate the js module from the C module:

`emcc example.cpp -o example.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_int_sqrt']" -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['ccall', 'cwrap']" -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1`

The C module :

```
#include <math.h>

extern "C" {

  int int_sqrt(int x) {
    return sqrt(x);
  }
}
```

Then importing the generated js module:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wasm example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import Module from './example.js'

      int_sqrt = Module.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number']);
      console.log(int_sqrt(64));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is failing because cwrap is not available on the Module object:

`Uncaught TypeError: Module.cwrap is not a function`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you're using `MODULARIZE`, you have to make an instance of the Module first.

```
import Module from './example.js'
const mymod = Module();
const int_sqrt = mymod.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number']);
console.log(int_sqrt(64));
```

You could also try the `MODULARIZE_INSTANCE` option.

You may need to wait for it to finish initialising - I'm not sure when the function is so simple. That would look like this:

```
import Module from './example.js'
Module().then(function(mymod) {
  const int_sqrt = mymod.cwrap('int_sqrt', 'number', ['number']);
  console.log(int_sqrt(64));
});
```

Comment: I get this error: Failed to compile. ./src/components/js_plumbing.js. SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ( (3:25) . > 3 |   var _scriptDir = import.meta.url;

Comment: @user2315094 Ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

emcc compile options:

```
emcc latuile.cpp bombix.cpp -o latuile-origine.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_latuile","_bombix"]' -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall","cwrap"]' -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1  -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -sMODULARIZE -s EXPORT_NAME="createMyModule"
```

Where latuile and bombix are the names of the C++ functions I want to call.

At the bottom of the produced file latuile-origine.js, I read:

```
export default createMyModule;
```

Then in the Javascript module that imports from latuile-origine.js, I have (notice the 'default' keyword):

```
import {default as createMyModule} from "./latuile-origine.js";
var Module;
function clientFunction()
{
...
    const bombix = Module.cwrap("bombix","string",["string","string","string","string"])
    const jsonResponse = bombix(rectdim, translations, sframe, slinks);
...
}

window.main = function main()
{
    createMyModule().then(function(mymod){
        Module = mymod;
    });
}
```